# Real time signals from multiple files leased via F_SETLEASE to a single lease holder are lost

Tags: linux, file, signal-processing, blocking

How to set up a reliable lease break real time signal notification to a single process which holds leases for multiple files?

Here is the context and the problem:

- When acquiring a lease with fcntl(fd, F_GETLEASE, ...) for a file
  opened with file descriptor fd, one can specify a real time signal,
  say fcntl(fd, F_SETSIG, SIGRTMIN+6), to be delivered to the lease
  holder when a lease breaker opens or truncates the file.
- The Linux documentation says real time signals are queued up by the
  kernel. So, one would expect  SIGRTMIN+6 to be queued up when
  multiple lease breakers each send a signal to the same lease holder.
- In my experiments it is indeed true if the leaseholder holds a lease
  for a single file descriptor, even if sometimes the lease holder
  blocks and then unblocks SIGRTMIN+6. However, if it holds leases for
  multiple files fd1, fd2, ..., and also sometimes blocks and unblocks
  SIGRTMIN+6, then SIGRTMIN+6 from breaking some of fdK are never
  delivered.

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know the answer to this question. One additional clue is that once during the stress test the OS kernel (Ubuntu 16.4 on Intel) recorded an internal assertion failure somewhere deep inside the kernel lease handling code. This seems to indicate a possible internal OS problem with the signal handling while blocking signals during lease breaks.

However, it was possible to redesign the application in such a way that the code which needed to be protected from being interrupted by SIGRTMIN+6 has been moved into a different process. The remaining program, now never attempting to block SIGRTMIN+6, works fine -- its signal handler catches all signals from the signal breakers all right.

Comment: More experiments indicate that the problem was not in blocking the real time signal, but in OS not queuing them up... so, the question becomes -- is this a known bug or there is something special that needs to be done for the realtime signals from multiple lease breakers to be queued up for the single lease holder?